# Quarkus Hibernate Query Translator Bug

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, hibernate-reactive

The following shows debug from my Quarkus app.  The translated SQL is not equivalent to the HQL Query.... The logic from the **BOLD section** Depending on how SQL parses the and/or logic, the two are not equivalent.  The following output is from my log showing the resulting HQL and SQL....  My original code is just a query string in the ORM ::find() method...

2022-09-12 14:17:36,027 DEBUG [org.hib.hql.int.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) HQL: from com.xxxxx.geo.GeoName where geo_country_code = :cc and geo_admin1_code = :admin1 and **((geo_feature_class = :class0 and geo_feature_code = :code0) or (geo_feature_class = :class1 and geo_feature_code = :code1) or (geo_feature_class = :class2 and geo_feature_code = :code2))** order by name
2022-09-12 14:17:36,027 DEBUG

[org.hib.hql.int.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) SQL: select geoname0_.geo_id as geo_id1_3_, geoname0_.geo_admin1_code as geo_admi2_3_, geoname0_.geo_admin2_code as geo_admi3_3_, geoname0_.geo_admin3_code as geo_admi4_3_, geoname0_.geo_admin4_code as geo_admi5_3_, geoname0_.geo_admin5_code as geo_admi6_3_, geoname0_.geo_alt_country_codes as geo_alt_7_3_, geoname0_.geo_alt_names as geo_alt_8_3_, geoname0_.geo_country_code as geo_coun9_3_, geoname0_.geo_dem as geo_dem10_3_, geoname0_.geo_elevation as geo_ele11_3_, geoname0_.geo_feature_class as geo_fea12_3_, geoname0_.geo_feature_code as geo_fea13_3_, geoname0_.geo_last_modified as geo_las14_3_, geoname0_.geo_latitude as geo_lat15_3_, geoname0_.geo_longitude as geo_lon16_3_, geoname0_.geo_name as geo_nam17_3_, geoname0_.geo_name_ascii as geo_nam18_3_, geoname0_.geo_population as geo_pop19_3_, geoname0_.geo_timezone as geo_tim20_3_ from geo.GeoNames geoname0_ where geo_country_code=? and geo_admin1_code=? and
**(geo_feature_class=? and geo_feature_code=? or geo_feature_class=? and geo_feature_code=? or geo_feature_class=? and geo_feature_code=?)**
order by geoname0_.geo_name

Comment: You will need to provide some more information like the HQL query and the expected SQL query. It would be also good to have the hibernate entities.

Comment: I updated the original example to provide a better example.... I think it comes down to how SQL parses the and/or but I am searching for 3 distinct class.feature combinations... it is not intuitive as to how the bold text above would get processed

Comment: Just to make sure. `and` has precedence over `or`. That means you can leave away the brackets around the and conditions. That also means the HQL and SQL are the same, as far as I can see it.